# Hive query drops null values with "not column=value" where clause

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

**table1 data sample:**

```
year month day utmsource
2017 03    26  NULL
2017 03    27  NULL
2017 03    27  facebook
2017 03    27  newsletter
2017 03    27  banner
2017 03    27  facebook
```

**expected selection:**

```
year month day utmsource
2017 03    27  NULL
2017 03    27  newsletter
2017 03    27  banner
```

**My Hive queries:**

```
-- result = 0, it did not include the NULL utmsource record
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN utmsource IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as amountnull
FROM table1
WHERE year=2017 AND month=03 AND day=27 AND NOT utmsource="facebook"

-- result = 1 the NULL utmsource record is included
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN utmsource IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as amountnull
FROM table1
WHERE year=2017 AND month=03 AND day=27 AND (utmsource IS NULL OR NOT utmsource="facebook")

-- also returns 0, the NULL utmsource record is not included
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN utmsource IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as amountnull
FROM table1
WHERE year=2017 AND month=03 AND day=27 AND NOT utmsource <=> 'facebook';
```

**Questions:**

1. Could someone explain this behaviour?
2. Can i change a setting to
   retrieve the result of query 2 without adding the extra OR
   functionality in my query? => not equals includes null values in result

Comment: `NOT NULL` --> `NULL` --> not true

Comment: This code is a complete mess. Please give a data sample instead.

Answer (score 4):

What you want is a `NULL`-safe equality (or inequality) operator.  In ANSI SQL, there is an operator called `is distinct from`.  Hive appears to use the MySQL version, which is `<=>`.  So, you can do:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN utmsource IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as amountnull
FROM tablename
WHERE year=2017 AND month=03 AND day=27 AND NOT utmsource <=> 'facebook';
```

This operator is described in the [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-RelationalOperators).

I should also point out that you might find this a simpler formulation for the `SELECT`:

```
SELECT (COUNT(*) - COUNT(utmsource)) as amountnull
FROM tablename
WHERE year=2017 AND month=03 AND day=27 AND NOT utmsource <=> 'facebook';
```

Although, overall, this would appear to be the simplest:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)as amountnull
FROM tablename
WHERE year=2017 AND month=03 AND day=27 AND utmsource IS NULL;
```

The comparison to `'Facebook'` is unnecessary.

Comment: the documentation for this operand states: "Returns same result with EQUAL(=) operator for non-null operands, but returns TRUE if both are NULL, FALSE if one of the them is NULL." in my case, one of them is NULL, so the clause returns FALSE instead of the desired TRUE. The utmsource IS NULL where clause doesn't count the records with an utmsource different from "facebook". The sum(null) was included to show the absence of null values

Comment: @JMordijck . . . Exactly.  And when you do `NOT false` you get true.  That is what you want.  Otherwise, you have `NOT NULL` which is `NULL`, and not what you want.

Comment: that sounds good, but when i execute your query, it also returns 0 as the result. When I do a SELECT * instead of the count, it only shows records with utmsource NOT NULL and not equal to facebook. I would like to include the NULL utmsource records in this result

Comment: @JMordijck . . . Interesting.  I can't account for bugs in Hive.  Here is an example of it working in MySQL:  http://rextester.com/l/mysql_online_compiler.